# How to shade bars in bar graph by axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to shade this graph by 2008 as a cut point? Like, before 2008 all share one color, after 2008 use another color.

[image]

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample input. This is needed to create, test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you need a vector that is the length of the amount of bars that you have that supplies the color.
you could try something like this:

```
color = ifelse(date < 2008, 'red', 'green')
```

you have to adjust the test accordingly.

Then you provdide the color to the plot

```
ggplot(aes(fill = color))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `annotate` function with `rect` as the option for geom:

```r
# Add rectangles
p + annotate(
  geom = "rect", 
  xmin=c(2,4), 
  xmax=c(3,5), 
  ymin=c(20,10), 
  ymax=c(30,20), 
  alpha=0.2, 
  color="blue", 
  fill="blue"
)
```

See https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/233-add-annotations-on-ggplot2-chart.html